# Align 6 divs content vertical

Tags: html, css

How would i align all these 6 divs vertically in a 3x3 pattern so that the top and bottom divs content are aligned with each other so it looks good. i've tried some vertical-align: middle; with no sucess.

It's a must to be 100% responsive and that the number also is centered and aligned so whatever number gets there is aligned.

```css
.top-right-container {
 position: absolute;
 border: 1px solid white;
 height: 20%;
 width: 50%;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
}

.stats-container {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid white;
 width: 75%;
 height: 80%;
}

.Agility,
.Stamina,
.Respect,
.Intelligence,
.Strength,
.Cash {
 display: inline-block;
 color: black;
}

.Agility,
.Intelligence {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10%;
}

.Stamina,
.Strength {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.Respect,
.Cash {
 margin-right: 10%;
 float: right;
}

.stats-container h2 {
 font-family: Marker-Felt;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: calc(0.7vh + 1.2vw);
}

.stats-container p {
 margin: 5%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: calc(0.5vh + 0.8vw);
}

.top-stats,
.bottom-stats {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-right-container">
      <div class="stats-container">
        <div class="top-stats">
        <div class="Agility">
          <h2>Agility</h2>
          <p>10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Stamina">
          <h2>Stamina</h2>
          <p>10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Respect">
          <h2>Respect</h2>
          <p>10</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-stats">
        <div class="Intelligence">
          <h2>Intelligence</h2>
          <p>10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Strength">
          <h2>Strength</h2>
          <p>10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cash">
          <h2>Cash</h2>
          <p>10</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Simply put a `<br />` tag after each div

Comment: @Shaybi `<br>` does not use or need a closing slash and never has. Using `<br>` for styling is bad practice. Learn CSS instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the **Flexbox**:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}

.stats-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.top-stats,
.bottom-stats {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.Agility,
.Stamina,
.Respect,
.Intelligence,
.Strength,
.Cash {
  flex: 1;
}

.stats-container h2 {
  font-size: calc(0.7vh + 1.2vw);
}

.stats-container p {
  font-size: calc(0.5vh + 0.8vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-right-container">
  <div class="stats-container">
    <div class="top-stats">
      <div class="Agility">
        <h2>Agility</h2>
        <p>10</p>
      </div>
      <div class="Stamina">
        <h2>Stamina</h2>
        <p>10</p>
      </div>
      <div class="Respect">
        <h2>Respect</h2>
        <p>10</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-stats">
      <div class="Intelligence">
        <h2>Intelligence</h2>
        <p>10</p>
      </div>
      <div class="Strength">
        <h2>Strength</h2>
        <p>10</p>
      </div>
      <div class="Cash">
        <h2>Cash</h2>
        <p>10</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## responsive 2 rows and 6 boxes

Here is some code you can work with.
The container of all the divs  `.container`  will take 100% of the page eg. its  `<body>` .
The rows  `.statRow`  will take 100% of its parent the container.
Now the boxes  `.box`  will take 33% of its parent width.
Then adding 3 of these boxes 33%+33%+33% will take up 99% of the container.

Additionally borders usually take up more space so width + border is its actual width.
This is fixed with chancing the elements **box-sizing** to **border-box**.

```css
.container {
  border: 10px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.statRow {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  border: 10px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="statBubble">
    <div class="box">
      <h5>Agility</h5>
      <p>10</p>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="box">
      <h5>Strength</h5>
      <p>10</p>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="box">
      <h5>Stat</h5>
      <p>number</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="statRow">
    <div class="box">
      <h5>Wisdom</h5>
      <p>100</p>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="box">
      <h5>Stat</h5>
      <p>number</p>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="box">
      <h5>Stat</h5>
      <p>number</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```